# Convert raw hex to readable hex in perl?

Tags: perl, serial-port, hex

I have written a little perl app to reads the serial port. When I run my little script I receive data but it's written in unreadable signs.. it shows like *I??. However if I do

```
perl test.pl | hexdump
```

I get the required data. And the hex data makes sense to me. Does anyone know how I can get this output using perl without using hexdump?
Right now I use print ($data) to print my data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Raw hex" doesn't mean anything; what you've got is a string of bytes that you want to convert to a textual representation. To do that you can use [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html). For example,

```
my $bytes = read_from_serial_port();
my $hex = unpack 'h*', $bytes;
```

Use `H` instead of `h` if you want the opposite endianness. (I always forget which is which.)